# android EditText what inputType to avoid text suggestions

Tags: android, text, android-edittext, autosuggest

one of my biggest peeves is how some android keyboards make text suggestions come up with no way to hide the keyboard. I think this has something to do with the kind of editable field is being focused.

What inputType will make this never happen? I never want to see android word suggestions when I am trying to have a user log in, for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html#TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS

Comment: this set me on the right track, I used `android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textVisiblePassword"` because it looks like the first one is not in all vendor builds of android

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it programmatically, then you can use the following code to avoid text suggestions on all keyboard types.

```
//assume an EditText object with name myEditText
myEditText.setInputType(myEditText.getInputType() | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
```

> InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS does not seem to work as
>   expected on all keyboards whereas
>   InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD has the drawback that
>   it also disables toggling the language in the keyboard and the swipe
>   gesture to add the text.